# Formatting USB stick via GParted - unallocated space?

Tags: usb

Why is is most of this unallocated space when I just used the USB the other day to install eOS, and the File Manager shows that all the files for eOS are still on there?

I am just trying to get the USB back to its original state, with no files / default format. How do I do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `/dev/sdb` is your USB stick, just delete the `/dev/sdb2` partition then create a single partition from the resulting single unallocated chunk then format it to FAT32 or any format you want.